My register route giving 404 error but the homepage route is working
MY SERVER.JS file for my backend
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute");

const app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://authz-app.vercel.app"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

// Routes
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Home Page");
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

MY USERROUTE
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { registerUser } = require("../controllers/userController");

console.log("Inside userRoute.js");

router.post("/register", registerUser);

console.log("Router setup for POST /register");

module.exports = router;

MY USER CONTROLLER
const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
  res.send("Register user");
};

module.exports = {
  registerUser,
};

I hope you're doing well. I'm reaching out because I've encountered an issue with my Node.js server setup and I'm seeking some guidance or suggestions to resolve it.
Problem Description:
I have set up a Node.js server using Express to handle user registration requests. The server is expected to process POST requests to the endpoint /api/users/register for user registration. However, when I send a POST request to this endpoint using Postman, I receive an error message saying "Cannot POST //api/users/register."
Key Details:
Server Framework: Node.js with Express
Middleware Used: express.json(), express.urlencoded(), cors, cookie-parser, body-parser
Database: MongoDB for data storage
Endpoint: /api/users/register
Expected Method: POST with JSON data for user registration
Steps Taken:
Defined the route in userRoute.js to handle POST requests to /register.
Implemented the registerUser controller function in userController.js to process user registration logic.
Configured middleware in server.js to parse request bodies and handle CORS.
Troubleshooting Attempts:
Verified the server configuration and route setup.
Checked middleware order to ensure correct request body parsing.
Inspected client-side request setup in Postman with correct method (POST) and endpoint (http://localhost:4000/api/users/register).
Restarted the server after making changes to the code.
Current Status:
The server is running without errors.
The homepage (/) is accessible and returns the expected response.
However, the registration endpoint (/api/users/register) is not handling POST requests as expected.
Request for Assistance:
I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps that could help me resolve this issue. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has expertise in Node.js and Express routing, your advice would be invaluable.

"Cannot POST //api/users/register"... this looks like you've included an extra slash in your request URL. Are you sure you're trying http://localhost:4000/api/users/register and not http://localhost:4000//api/users/register?

Also, don't include two JSON body parsers. Remove app.use(bodyParser.json())

I am tryng http://localhost:4000/api/users/register but i get same error. I have also removed the body parser., still the same error
